# No Access Control Allow Origin, Origin Null

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome

The following submits a form to a php page using jQuery post function and then prints the response on the same html page for the user. The code works perfect on Microsoft Edge browser__ it posts and then prints the response from php page but does not work on any other browser I tried browsers such as Firefox 5.0, IE11 and Chrome. However, I inspected on Chrome and saw the following Error: "XMLHttp request cannot load localhost/products/s1.php No 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested source. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access". Please How can I fix this. Any help will be highly appreciated.
The Error from chrome can be found in the image below:
[Error from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEVFA.png)

and here is success from Microsoft Edge:
[Microsoft Edge success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYdla.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because other browsers (not Edge) believe that you are trying to make an Ajax request to a host (domain) different from the domain the page is on.  As a security measure the browser will first ask the server if this request is acceptable. Unless the server is configured to approve the request, the browser will never actually send the request.  This security feature is called the [Same Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474336/same-origin-policy-in-layman-terms)

Let's see whether a simple fix is sufficient first: In your Ajax request, try changing the url from `localhost/products/s1.php` to `/products/s1.php`

Comment: I changed it and still see the following error XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </meta>.
Location: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/products/s11.php
Line Number 13, Column 4:

Comment: A parsing error is different from the error you originally reported. Your original error was "*No 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present*".  If I helped you get past that error, then select the answer.  For your new error, try to solve it on your own; if you cannot open a new issue.

Comment: the former was from Chrome and the later was from Firefox and the errors captured exist before applying the changes and after applying the changes. After applying changes Chrome Chrome error did not change, and Microsoft Edge still loads the response perfectly well. I haven't got rid of the error. But I want to thank you so much @Beetle Juice.

Comment: Please one more help from you @Beetle Juice, since this works well on Edge, if I deploy this file to production server, would the remote server resolve the issue would it recognize that it's not cross site request

Answer (score 0):

Putting this first at the top of my php file where the request is submitted solved my problem:

**See below:**

```html
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 100000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
```

However, you may not need to use this in production enviroment unless you are sure you really mean to allow cors.